# Listening to messages in SLACK

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands

In SLACK docs, it says

The re.compile() method can be used instead of a string for more granular matching. Below is the code example from Slack.

```
import re

@app.message(re.compile("(hi|hello|hey)"))
def say_hello_regex(say, context):
    # regular expression matches are inside of context.matches
    greeting = context['matches'][0]
    say(f"{greeting}, how are you?")
```

I am trying to modify this a bit as such

```
@app.message(re.compile(r"phone.*|phone number. *"))
def phone(arguments):
#do this
```

But Slack is unable to route  "phone 123-123-1234" to that listener. However, if I type "phone.*" (literal string), it matches.

Can someone help on this? Am i missing something here?

Comment: Do you have any other listeners? I've tested the regex with your input and it matched. One thing to bear in mind is that from my testing listeners are matched in order, so if you had a function matching (".*") defined first it would match every input, subsequent functions would never match